# MySQL LEFT JOIN multiple tables from same source table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
companyContacts
addresses
states
phoneNumbers
```

And I need to do a LEFT JOIN on `addresses`, `states`, and `phoneNumbers`. I need to connect `phoneNumbers` and `addresses` with `companyContacts`, and need to connect `states` with `addresses`.

I can do a select like the following to grab everything. However, If someone has an address and not a phone number, it will not return a result. How do I make it so that both `phoneNumbers` and `addresses` are joined from `companyContacts`?

```
SELECT * FROM
    companyContacts AS c
    LEFT JOIN phoneNumbers AS p
        ON c.entityID = p.entityID
    LEFT JOIN addresses AS a
        ON p.entityID = a.entityID
    LEFT JOIN states AS s
        ON a.stateID = s.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  companyContacts AS c
LEFT JOIN phoneNumbers AS p
   ON c.entityID = p.entityID
LEFT JOIN addresses AS a
   ON c.entityID = a.entityID
LEFT JOIN states AS s
   ON a.stateID = s.id
```

If you join on the `companyContacts.entityId` to both the `phoneNumbers` and `addresses` then you will return records even if there is not a phone number or address. The way you had it written the phone number needed to exist to return an address

Comment: Wow, I swear I tried that and it told me "c.entityID is not defined" or something along those lines... but it seems to work. Did I seriously make a typo and not catch it?

Comment: @Jeff it is possible, I have definitely done it before. A second pair of eyes is always nice. :)